# How to install ubuntu server on HP 819185-421 proliant microserver?

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, usb, hp

I have bought a HP 819185-421 proliant microserver, and I want to install ubuntu server before buying hard disks. So, I burn Ubuntu 14.04 in a usb(4GB) using the software "ISO to USB", but after choosing the usb in the bios, it said "no OS found, please remove units without OS and reboot" (something like that, I do not remember the exacts words). I know that if I switch off the server, the usb does not save the configuration, but I only want to install the ubuntu server, make some test and after that, buy hard disk.

Thanks for all

Comment: If your server is booting in UEFI you need to create a UEFI boot USB. Your server will need hard disks no matter what OS you decide on so I don't see why you haven't gone ahead and ordered them based upon how much data you will be storing on them. The OS itself will need 10 to 60 GB.

Answer (score 0):

## Regarding your intention there are two issues:

1. Ubuntu server is not a live cd/live usb. Thus you need a harddisk to install ubuntu server.
2. To bring the ubuntu server iso on usb, use dd. (All other tools failed with the server edition when I did it):

> dd if=ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc && sync

(adapt iso file name and usb device appropriately)

If you insist in doing a test ride, you can use the **ubuntu desktop edition**. This is a live cd/live usb. (can be created with dd as stated above, or other tools)

### Hint: Why aren't you using ubuntu server ***16.04LTS***?

It has long term support too and is newer (=support for more hardware)

### How much disk space is needed?

Ubuntu Server 16.04LTS takes about 2.2GB space in its default installation. (Ubuntu + SSH server)